# How to get value from url in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url

I am having the url as follows:

```
http://test.com/#/mya/classified/42/
```

How can I fetch 42 from this usl in angularjs?
Is there any way in angularjs $location to fetch the same?.

Comment: Are you using states for URL routing? Anyway, show how do you manage URL routing in your app. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I am using ui-router.

Comment: .state('mya.viewOrder', {
                abstract: true,
                url: 'orders/:id/',
                templateUrl: './partials/mya/order/view.html',
                controller: 'MyaOrderViewCtrl'
            })

Comment: try this, i guess it should give your params  in url var location = $location.search(); ...and if you have many params in your url ..you can choose particular param using $location.search().paramName;

Comment: It gives param values only. search function process the values after ?.

Comment: try like $location.search().id; and see

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what [`$stateParams`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#url-parameters) service is for:

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams',
    function ($scope, $stateParams) {
        console.log($stateParams.id);
}]);
```